# How to call json.Unmarshal inside UnmarshalJSON without causing stack overflow?

Tags: go, struct

How can I create a method UnmarshalJSON inside a struct, use json.Unmarshal inside without causing stack overflow?

```
package xapo

type Xapo struct {}

func (x Xapo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("done!")
    return nil
}
```

Can someone explain me why the stack overflow happens? Can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the purpose of the function?

Comment: `json.Unmarshal` will recognise the type of `&x` and eventually call `x.UnmarshalJSON` again etc etc. I think this could be fixed with some extra type layers, but it all depend on why you need this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you may be trying to do custom unmarshaling by using the default unmarshaler and then post-processing the data. However, as you've discovered, the obvious way of trying this causes an infinite loop!

The usual workaround is to create a new type using your type, use the default unmarshaler on an instance of the new type, post-process the data, and then finally cast to the original type and assign back to the target instance.  Note that you'll want to implement UnmarshalJSON on a pointer type.

For example:

```
func (x *Xapo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  // Create a new type from the target type to avoid recursion.
  type Xapo2 Xapo

  // Unmarshal into an instance of the new type.
  var x2 Xapo2
  err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x2)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Perform post-processing here.
  // TODO

  // Cast the new type instance to the original type and assign.
  *x = Xapo(x2)
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'll have to update my shoddy solution in my code to match with aliasing. Pre-alias, I created a local anonymous struct with identical structure. The struct never changed, thankfully, but now I don't have to worry about it ever doing so. Thanks.